# What are the XSS dangers of passing JS functions in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, xss

It is simple enough to create a JSON object like this:

> { "key": "value", "myFunction": function() { alert('hi'); } }

and pass it from the server to the script where I can call myFunction(). Sure enough, the function works and I get an alert: "hi". For me this could be a very useful way of keeping the script size small.
However, I believe there are XSS dangers in passing functions rather than just data via JSON. Could someone explain what these are and, if appropriate, what steps can be taken to negate them?

Answer (score 2):

`function` isn't part of [JSON](http://json.org/) because JSON isn't JavaScript.

Most libraries are using a JSON parser (when they can, the [browser's one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON)). So this won't be parsed correctly. Although using `eval` to parse JSON is **evil**. `eval` is evil in general.

And you're loading JavaScript all the time using `<script>`, so I don't see the problem here about XSS.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you are loading and parsing the JSON. If you are using jQuery and loading the data via AJAX, then that data is passed to the browser's built-in JSON-parser which doesn't support function as explained by greut.
http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/misc/json/index.html

However if you are loading it through either JSONP (wrapping a function around it), by the JSON adding it directly in a script tag at the end of the page like for instance Socialcast does, then it's vulnerable.
http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/misc/json/index2.html

If you are having problems with this last one, you should remember that JSON values (and keys) should always be wrapped in "". So if you are building JSON from untrusted data, you have to remember to JSON encode it. It's sort of similar to Javascript encoding, except JSON has some additional quirks. For instance you can have a valid JSON file, that is not valid javascript, because it contains characters allowed in JSON, but which need to be encoded in javascript.